# MPMediaPlayerController turn hide user interface elements permanently

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-interface, mpmediaplayercontroller

I using MPMediaPlayerController and i need hide elements of UI permanently.
But i can see it when player start play video, 2 seconds later it hide.
I using:

`setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeHidden`.

[image: MPMediaPlayerController]

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://catholictvhd-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ctvhd_1@88148/index_3_av-p.m3u8"]];


[player.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
player.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
CGSize maxSize;



if([[UIScreen screens]count] > 1) {
    [self logIt:@"External screen is available"];
    newwindow = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
    // There is a external display.
    UIScreenMode *maxScreenMode;
    for(int i = 0; i < [[[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1] availableModes]count]; i++)
    {
        UIScreenMode *current = [[[[UIScreen screens]objectAtIndex:1]availableModes]objectAtIndex:i];
        if(current.size.width > maxSize.width)
        {
            maxSize = current.size;
            maxScreenMode = current;
        }
    }
    UIScreen *external = [[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];
    external.currentMode = maxScreenMode;

    [self logIt:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",maxScreenMode]];
    newwindow.screen = external;
    // setting external display size.
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    //CGSize size = CGSizeMake(1024.0f, 768.0f);
    CGSize size = maxSize;
    CGRect frame = player.view.frame;
    frame.origin = point;
    frame.size.width = size.width;
    frame.size.height = size.height;
    [player.view setFrame:frame];
    [player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeHidden];

    [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;


    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
```

Comment: have you tried player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

Comment: Thats hide interface and video too only sound plays.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much this really helpful. Later not see video because this stream server of this channel so bagly and just send without video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;  // to hide controls
```

Before playing the video you have to add subview as MPMoviePlayerController

Add this line before play

```
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```